# disable DebuggerStepThrough for partial class

Tags: c#, debugging, auto-generate

I have set of classes that are auto generated by tool. but all classes are marked with `DebuggerStepThrough` attribute

the classes are partial, so I can write my code for that class in separate file, however `DebuggerStepThrough` in auto generated part of partial class will affect entire class.

How can I disable this behavior for `DebuggerStepThrough`, removing `DebuggerStepThrough` is obvious solution but that's not the answer I'm looking for. I don't want to touch auto generated code. also skipping from auto generated code is ok, but  I want to be able to debug my own code.

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
partial class Foo
{
   // auto generated
}

// how to exclude this part from DebuggerStepThrough?
partial class Foo
{
   // user code
}
```

Comment: In Visual Studio, go to Tools - Options, scroll to Debugging/General and uncheck the box next to Enable Just My Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking to do is impossible as far as I know.  Partial class attributes are merged at compile time.  So your two partial classes:

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
partial class Foo
{
    // auto generated
}

partial class Foo
{
    // user code
}
```

Compile to this:

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
class Foo
{
    // auto generated

    // user code
}
```

Comment: I guess, GitHub is next place to ask for solving it. https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues